# 500 instead of 404 and 500 throws 500 itself

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site in a subfolder in which I have a .htaccess file which works quite fine, but if the rules dont find anything, it raises a 500 internal server error istead of 404, however I thought I would solve it by adding a 500 Error document,
but the 500 Error page (aside from classic 500 message) says:

> "Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

So I have a two questions:

1. Why is 500 raised instead of 404?
2. What is causing the "additional" error while handling 500 Error document?

This is my *.htaccess* so far:

```
DirectorySlash On

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysubdir/

ErrorDocument 404 /mysubdir/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /mysubdir/500.php

RewriteRule ^folderexcludedone(/|$) - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^folderexcludedtwo(/|$) - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1/ [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ $1.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ $1.php?$2=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
DirectorySlash On

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysubdir/

ErrorDocument 404 /mysubdir/404.php

RewriteRule ^(folderexcludedone|folderexcludedtwo)(/|$) - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1/ [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?$2=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Ok it seems to work for all needed rules now :) - so could you please explain more why it works now? :) And why cant I have a custom 500 error document?

Comment: Actually you can have custom 500 now :) I just skipped it so that we don't hide the actual problem. You were getting 500 because of looping problem since your regex was little incorrect. I made last edit to correct a minor mistake I made in your last rule. (I tested all your rules one by one and in the last one I had `([^/])` in place of `([^/]+)`).

Comment: The stars (`*`) instead of plus signs (`+`) were causing the looping error when not found => 500 - werent they? :) Regexps can be really tricky ... Anyway thank yo very much, you have been more than helpful - as always :)

Comment: You're most welcome. Yes exactly that `.*` and then `/?$` were causing 500 looping errors. Regex can be tricky but they're powerful as well :)